# Given $\cos x = -\frac14 \sqrt{3}$, find possible values of $\tan x$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Given $$\cos x = -\frac{1}{4}\sqrt 3$$
>
> Find possible values of $\tan x$. Write your answers exactly in surd form.

Please can somebody help? I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: You seem relatively new to this site, so welcome! Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Answer (score 2):

Use $\tan^2 x =\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}-1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$ \cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}= 1 \implies \frac{1}{\cos^2{x}} = 1+\frac{\sin^2{x}}{\cos^2{x}} = 1+\tan^2{x}. $$

Make sure you check that all solutions you find are possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why the warning about "possible"? $\tan x$ takes all real values, and most complex ones, too (all except $\pm i$, to be precise).

Comment: @ProfessorVector I felt it sensible to give as a piece of general advice for this sort of question, given that the OP seems to not know very much about it.

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos x=-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt 3$ then 
$$\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}$$

$$\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}}{-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt 3}=-\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}$$

$\cos x$ is negative between $90°$ and $270°$, while tangent is negative between $90°$ and $180°$  and in this interval  $\color{red}{\tan x=-\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}}$

and positive between $180°$ and $270°$ and in this interval we have  $\color{red}{\tan x=\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}}$

Comment: Great help! However, the question also says 'find possible values of tan(x)'. Does this mean that I should have multiple answers. Wouldn't you just add or subtract 180 from the answer above to get every possible answer as the tan curve repeats every 180 degrees? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: No. no. They asked for the value of the **tangent**, and there are just the two I've found. Do not confuse with *angles*: angles with those tangent values are infinite: you can get each one adding or subtracting  $180°$ to the previous one